# Filesystem on a block device that now has another name?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount

Here's the scenario:

1. I'm attaching a disk to a KVM guest VM, lets say 'vdb'
2. Now I create a partition on 'vdb' and format it as ext4 (vdb1)
3. I mount 'vdb1' and write some data
4. I unmount the 'vdb1'
5. I detach the disk from the VM and reattach it
6. It is now appear as 'vdc' (block device name changed)
7. Runing 'fdisk -l' on 'vdc' shows no partitions and I can't mount the partition I created on step 2

What went wrong? How would it be possible to access the data on that disk? Are filesystems sensitive to device name changes?

Answer (score 0):

if you worry about disk name change, you can use Fs label or uuid to mount your fs, anyway if you don't deleted the partition table on virtual disk, the partition table are still there, use dmesg in you vm guest to see the device, attach and detach vm disk don't destroy any disk data